# How to fetch entire org. metadata into a git repository using salesforce dx

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to teach myself salesforce dx  and to start development I am trying to create a git repository of my existing sandbox org. where lots of code and customisation is already done.

**I am unable to figure out how to create a git repository with all the metadata from my sandbox. Is there a way to do it via salesforce DX ? or do I need to do it through any other means.**

So far I had been coding directly in developer console so never came across this issue. Now I have setup Visual Studio Code with the official salesforce plugins installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this directly with DX.

First, authenticate:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com/ -a sbname
```

Create a package.xml file or a package in Setup. See the Metadata API documentation for how to create a package.xml file if you desire to go that route.

After that, you will then retrieve (example uses package.xml, fix parameters as necessary):

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -s -r src -k package.xml -u sbname
```

Then convert:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r src -d force-app
```

---

Edit: You can now skip the conversion process and use the package.xml or package name directly. This skips the conversion step.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -n "Package Name With Spaces"
```

Or:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -x package.xml
```

Comment: ERROR running force:mdapi:retrieve:  Unexpected argument: true
See more help with --help

Comment: @gpresland Thanks for letting me know. Since this answer, Boolean flags no longer accept "true" or "false", but automatically default to false and are true when present. I will amend this answer.